# How can I add config transformation to web forms application in VS 2015?

Tags: .net, web-config, web.config-transform

I am trying to add a new Config transform to a web site in VS 2015, and do not have the option when I right click the we.config. Is there something I am missing?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you already did it and it broke you might want to install Visual Studio extension Slow Cheetah that does allow you to transform config files on build.

[Here's the link to Visual Studio Marketplace.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)